# Laravel 5 add results from query in a foreach to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, addition

I have a problem in my Laravel 5 application. 
My controller-method contains a foreach, which should iterate over a previous Eloquent-result-array (it is named $zipcodes). So each zipcode is used to fill a query, which result returns an Article-object (named $article). 
Every end of iteration it should add the Article-result to an array ($articles), which is used at the end of my method to display the Articles on my page.
Maybe there is a better option for the performing of the Article-query, not every iteration, but I don't know how.

**UPDATE**

This is working for my problem, without perform the query in a foreach: [Laravel multiple where clauses in query from given array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719951/laravel-multiple-where-clauses-in-query-from-given-array)

My code now is

```
// grabs all zipcodes matching the distance
$zipcodes = $this->getZipcodes($zipCoordinateId, $distance);

foreach ($zipcodes AS $key=>$val)
{
    $zipcodes[$key] = (array) $val;
}

$codes = array_column($zipcodes, 'zc_zip');

$articles = Article::whereIn('zipcode', $codes)->get();

return view('pages.intern.articles.index', compact('articles'));
```

**UPDATE END**

My SearchController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function getSearch(Request $request)
{
    if(($request->has('zipcode'))) {
        $zipcode = $request->input('zipcode');
        $distance = $request->input('distance');

        $zipCoordinateId = $this->getZipCoordindateId($zipcode);
        $zipcodes = $this->getZipcodes($zipCoordinateId, $distance);

        $articles = array();

        foreach($zipcodes as $value) {
            //$zipcode = $zipcodes[0]->zc_zip; // this is working
            $zipcode = $value->zc_zip;

            $article = Article::where('zipcode', $zipcode)->get();


           // add the $article each iteration to $articles
        }

        return view('pages.articles', compact('articles'));
    } else {
        return redirect('/articles');
    }
}

public function getZipCoordindateId($value) {
    $result = DB::table('zip_coordinates')
            ->where('zc_zip', '=' , $value)
            ->orWhere('zc_location_name', 'LIKE', $value)
            ->pluck('zc_id');
    return $result;
}

public function getZipcodes($id, $distance) {

    $result = DB::select(
        DB::raw("
            SELECT dest.zc_zip,
                ACOS(
                    SIN(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat))
                    + COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat))
                    * COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lon) - RADIANS(dest.zc_lon))
                ) * 6380 AS distance
            FROM zip_coordinates AS dest
            CROSS JOIN zip_coordinates AS src
            WHERE src.zc_id = :id
            HAVING distance < :distance
            ORDER BY distance"), array('id' => $id, 'distance' => $distance));

    return $result;
}
}
```

my view:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <h1>All Articles</h1>
<hr/>

<search>
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'intern/search']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('zipcode', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::select('distance', [
          '5' => '5 km',
          '10' => '10 km',
          '25' => '25 km',
          '50' => '50 km',
          ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Suchen', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</search>


@foreach($articles as $article)
    <article>
        <h2>
            <a href="{{ url('/articles', $article->id) }}">{{ $article->name }}</a>
        </h2>

        <div>
            <label>Description:</label>
            <p>{{ $article->description }}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>ZIPCODE:</label>
            {{ $article->zipcode }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Published:</label>
            {{ $article->published }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Rank:</label>
            {{ $article->rank }}
        </div>
    </article>
    <hr/>
@endforeach
@stop
```

Hope you can help me, thank you in advance.
quantatheist

**EDIT**

When I use

```
foreach($zipcodes as $key => $value)
        {
            $articles[] = Article::where('zipcode', $value->zc_zip)->get();
        }
        print_r($articles);
```

With another zipcode in the search and updated zipcodes of my articles, it prints (at the moment, there are three articles in my database, the both first have zipcodes, which are in the range of my new zipcode-search):

```
Array
(
[0] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => App\Article Object
                    (
                        [fillable:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => name
                                [1] => description
                                [2] => profile
                                [3] => driverlicense
                                [4] => zipcode
                                [5] => published
                                [6] => rank
                                [7] => contact
                                [8] => note
                                [9] => pictures
                                [10] => publisher
                            )

                        [connection:protected] => 
                        [table:protected] => 
                        [primaryKey:protected] => id
                        [perPage:protected] => 15
                        [incrementing] => 1
                        [timestamps] => 1
                        [attributes:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 5
                                [name] => Test1
                                [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
                                [profile] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                                [driverlicense] => yes
                                [published] => no
                                [rank] => 10
                                [contact] => 1
                                [pictures] => 
                                [zipcode] => 89429
                                [note] => 
                                [publisher] => 1
                                [created_at] => 2015-11-04 01:45:18
                                [updated_at] => 2015-11-04 10:07:24
                            )

                        [original:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 5
                                [name] => Test1
                                [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                                [profile] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                                [driverlicense] => yes
                                [published] => no
                                [rank] => 10
                                [contact] => 1
                                [pictures] => 
                                [zipcode] => 89429
                                [note] => 
                                [publisher] => 1
                                [created_at] => 2015-11-04 01:45:18
                                [updated_at] => 2015-11-04 10:07:24
                            )

                        [relations:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [hidden:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [visible:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [appends:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [guarded:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => *
                            )

                        [dates:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [dateFormat:protected] => 
                        [casts:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [touches:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [observables:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [with:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [morphClass:protected] => 
                        [exists] => 1
                        [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => App\Article Object
                    (
                        [fillable:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => name
                                [1] => description
                                [2] => profile
                                [3] => driverlicense
                                [4] => zipcode
                                [5] => published
                                [6] => rank
                                [7] => contact
                                [8] => note
                                [9] => pictures
                                [10] => publisher
                            )

                        [connection:protected] => 
                        [table:protected] => 
                        [primaryKey:protected] => id
                        [perPage:protected] => 15
                        [incrementing] => 1
                        [timestamps] => 1
                        [attributes:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6
                                [name] => Test2
                                [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
                                [profile] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                [driverlicense] => yes
                                [published] => no
                                [rank] => 3
                                [contact] => 1
                                [pictures] => 
                                [zipcode] => 89428
                                [note] => 
                                [publisher] => 1
                                [created_at] => 2015-11-04 01:45:38
                                [updated_at] => 2015-11-04 09:58:01
                            )

                        [original:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6
                                [name] => Test2
                                [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
                                [profile] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                [driverlicense] => yes
                                [published] => no
                                [rank] => 3
                                [contact] => 1
                                [pictures] => 
                                [zipcode] => 89428
                                [note] => 
                                [publisher] => 1
                                [created_at] => 2015-11-04 01:45:38
                                [updated_at] => 2015-11-04 09:58:01
                            )

                        [relations:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [hidden:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [visible:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [appends:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [guarded:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => *
                            )

                        [dates:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [dateFormat:protected] => 
                        [casts:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [touches:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [observables:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [with:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [morphClass:protected] => 
                        [exists] => 1
                        [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

**EDIT 2**

I print_r the articles from $articles = Article::all();, which uses the same return view('pages.articles', compact('articles')); and displays on the same site:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => App\Article Object
            (
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ...
                    )

                [connection:protected] => 
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ...
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ...
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            )

        [1] => App\Article Object
            (
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ..
                    )

                [connection:protected] => 
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ...
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ..
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            )

        [2] => App\Article Object
            (
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ..
                    )

                [connection:protected] => 
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (..
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        ..
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            )

    )

)
```

So the output from my print_r($articles) should be something like this.

**EDIT 3**

My current foreach is:

```
foreach($zipcodes as $key => $value)
        {
            //$code = $zipcodes[0]->zc_zip; // working, prints out one article
            //$article = Article::where('zipcode', $code)->get();
            $article = Article::where('zipcode', $value->zc_zip)->get();
            //print_r($article);
        }
        print_r($article);
```

Comment: Can you print_r($zipcodes)?

Comment: Yes, it shows: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [zc_zip] => 97204
            [distance] => 3.9266259510316
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [zc_zip] => 97218
            [distance] => 4.3622922988114
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [zc_zip] => 97236
            [distance] => 4.5967044919437
        )

)        EDIT: three items are correct, they are in the distance of 5. Sry

Comment: Try my answer if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
foreach($zipcodes as $key => $value)
{
    $articles[] = Article::where('zipcode', $value->zc_zip)->get();
}
return view('pages.articles', compact('articles'));
```

View:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
<article>
    <h2>
        <a href="{!! url('/articles', $article->id) !!}">{!! $article->name !!}</a>
    </h2>

    <div>
        <label>Description:</label>
        <p>{!! $article->description !!}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>ZIPCODE:</label>
        {!! $article->zipcode !!}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Published:</label>
        {!! $article->published !!}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Rank:</label>
        {!! $article->rank !!}
    </div>
</article>
<hr/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Am I right, that something like $articles (for my compact) is missing? No, not working.

Comment: can you print_r($value) again?

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [zc_zip] => 97204
    [distance] => 3.9266259510316
)
stdClass Object
(
    [zc_zip] => 97218
    [distance] => 4.3622922988114
)
stdClass Object
(
    [zc_zip] => 97236
    [distance] => 4.5967044919437
)

Comment: Try my answer. I think your compact is wrong. So I modified it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to talk about my view. it should display all articles from the database. So it has a @foreach($articles as $article) ... @endforeach

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )
Sounds good. This command is under the query. I let my compact with articles.

Comment: Change your compact to article

Comment: "Undefined variable: articles" in my view.

Comment: Change all your articles in your view to article

Comment: Undefined variable: article

Comment: I added the view in my first post. :)

Comment: Yes, it should be. But it can also be $articles as $article, right? So, is there none option to concat or add the result-object from the query to my array $articles in the Controller?

Comment: Yes. If you want to call `$articles` just change my answer to this `$articles = Article::where('zipcode', $value->zc_zip)->get();` And delete `$articles = array();`

Comment: @aldrin27 if you do it in this way you will be overriding the value each time in the foreach loop, you have to use the array sintax as follow : `$articles[] = Article::where('zipcode', $value->zc_zip)->get(); And delete $articles = array();`

Comment: You're confused with `{{ $data }}` with `{!! $data !!}`

Comment: I am! :D What was the difference and how to resolve it?

Comment: Thank you, but it has the same error. Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Comment: That's be cause you don't have id in the result. Try to delete `$article->id` This is your array `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [zc_zip] => 97204 [distance] => 3.9266259510316 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [zc_zip] => 97218 [distance] => 4.3622922988114 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [zc_zip] => 97236 [distance] => 4.5967044919437 ) )`

Comment: Can you print_r($articles)?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) ) Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) ) Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) )

Comment: When I try to delete the id, it prints an error, because the name is missing.

Comment: Above print_r was in the foreach. This is outside the foreach: Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) )

Comment: When I choose another zipcode (and change the zipcodes of the articles) it will prints out more. See my first post.

Comment: Try to change `$articles[]` to `$articles`

Comment: Without [] and the print_r outside the foreach it prints Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )

Comment: I think the error is in the query in where clause. Is it really zipcode?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I tried both queries in my mySQL-Database, they are working fine. The only problem is at the first query, when a town has many zipcodes. My query result will be the very first entry, but this is unnecessary. When I activate $zipcode = $zipcodes[0]->zc_zip; (and comment the method below), it prints my article with the resulting zipcode relative to the distance in my second query.

Comment: Does `$value->zc_zip` has a value when you print_r() it?

Comment: It prints "972049721897236" for 97204, 97218 and 97236 from getZipcodes().

Answer (score 0):

You have declared $articles = array(); and then you're passing $article (without the **s**) to compact function, that is why you get an undefined variable in your view, also when you are looping in the foreach you must do it like this :

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
....
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sorry, this was from editing my code to the solutions of aldrin27. It was there, as you wrote. :)

Comment: @quantatheist What error are you getting now? I still seeing that you have **$article** in the getSearch method and it have to be `$articles[] = Article::where('zipcode', $zipcode)->get();` otherwise you will be returning an empty array.

Comment: With your solution I'll get a "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id"-ErrorException.