# Laravel multiple where clauses in query from given array

Tags: sql, laravel, where-clause

I hope the title describes my problem good as enough.
I tried to make a geosearch-function in laravel. The queries as its own are correct. Now I try to get all articles from my table, whose match with the gotten zipcode of a former query. All functions I use you can found here: [Laravel 5 add results from query in a foreach to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511113/laravel-5-add-results-from-query-in-a-foreach-to-array)). But now I want to perform one query, within multiple or dynamic where clauses (with or).
The `print_r($zipcodes)` of my former query (get all zipcodes in a range from a zipcode `$zipcodes = $this->getZipcodes($zipCoordinateId, $distance);`) outputs:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [zc_zip] => 13579
        [distance] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [zc_zip] => 12345
        [distance] => 2.228867736739
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [zc_zip] => 98765
        [distance] => 3.7191570094844
    )
)
```

So how should my query in laravel should look, when I want to perform following?

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE zipcode = '13579'
OR zipcode = '98765'
OR zipcode = '12345';
```

Thank you in advance,
quantatheist

**UPDATE**

With the solution from balintant this is working fine. Here is my code:

```
// grabs all zipcodes matching the distance
$zipcodes = $this->getZipcodes($zipCoordinateId, $distance);

foreach ($zipcodes AS $key=>$val)
{
    $zipcodes[$key] = (array) $val;
}

$codes = array_column($zipcodes, 'zc_zip');

$articles = Article::whereIn('zipcode', $codes)->get();

return view('pages.intern.articles.index', compact('articles'));
```

Comment: Use `IN(...)` sql construction. In Laravel there is `whereIn()` Builder method. Take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both the `whereIn` and `orWhere` scopes. The first one better fits to your current example. Also, you can use `array_column` to get all the real zip codes from the array above.

```php
$query->whereIn('zip', [12,34,999])->get();
// > array
```

**Update:**

When you want to use `array_column` to get the specific subvalues of the array (like `zc_zip`) you must first transform it's childs to an array. **If it's a model you must transform it easily with `toArray()`**.

```php
$zip_objects = [
    (object) [ 'zc_zip' => 13579, 'distance' => 0 ],
    (object) [ 'zc_zip' => 12345, 'distance' => 2.228867736739 ],
    (object) [ 'zc_zip' => 98765, 'distance' => 3.7191570094844 ],
];

foreach ( $zip_objects AS $key=>$val )
{
    $zip_objects[$key] = (array) $val;
}

$zip_codes = array_column($zip_objects, 'zc_zip');

var_dump($zip_codes);
// > array(3) {
// >  [0]=>
// >  int(13579)
// >  [1]=>
// >  int(12345)
// >  [2]=>
// >  int(98765)
// > }
```

Comment: Okay nice. But how do I make my query with '$zipcodes->zc_zip' instead of [12,34,999]?